# How to start jx cluster and server after reboot?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-x

I created a minikube cluster using:

```
jx create cluster minikube
```

Everything worked as aspected.
After restarting my computer the cluster and the jenkins server are not running e.g. `jx open` results in:

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443:
```

How to restart the cluster and server as `jx create cluster` did it? I did not find any suitable command in the docs. Thanks!